# Error trying to display the nested representation of a related GenericForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to display the nested representation of a related `GenericForeignKey` in Django Rest Framework. This is what I have tried:

```
class ContentRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Membership):
            return MemberSerializer

        return None


class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    content_object = ContentRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'content_object')
```

Which gives the following error:

```
<class 'app.serializers.MemberSerializer'> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not only return the class MemberSerializer class but a serialized instance of it. Change this line to:

```
return MemberSerializer(value).data
```